# hide image using jquery if it has no src

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my image doesnt contain a src then i want to hide it using visibility hidden:

```
<img border="0" src="" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;" id="EntityPic543">
```

How can i do this with jquery?

Comment: Please note that if your `img` tag has `width` & `height` attributes it will still occupy some space when using `visibility:hidden`. Most of the answers will make your `img` `display:none;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('img').filter(function(index){return $(this).attr('src')==='';}).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each(function(){
     (!this.src || $(this).prop("src")) && $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Thanks to @GeorgeMauer

Comment: Why `jquery(this)` just to get an src attribute?

Comment: Also note that if the attribute is missing entirely this will not hide  it since `attr('src')` is undefined (going through the DOM will). If you really want to keep this form then `$(this).attr('src')||''` will do it.

Comment: Try my code it will work 100% even if there is src attribute is missing.

Comment: `$('<img>').attr('src')==""` will return false so the image will not hide http://jsfiddle.net/LafSw/

Comment: OK. updated my answer. it is hybrid of your answer and mine. Your solution  `!this.src && $(this).hide()` will not work if the image already has attribute `src=""`
http://jsfiddle.net/LafSw/2/

Comment: It's the inverse, its not working if src is left off. The interesting thing about that is the src attribute seems to be getting filled out automatically by chrome in that case (try it out, its weird).  The above is a bit overkill, you can solve this with just `$(this).attr('src')` http://jsfiddle.net/LafSw/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function() { 
  !this.src && $(this).hide()
});
```

Comment: This will not work if placed in head tag. you have to add it to document ready

Comment: That is true, yes, I assumed he was already but good point. It's not a great idea to include all scripts from the head btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this without any loop:

```
$('img[src=""]').hide();
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xx62q/3/)**

Comment: Not exactly in the OP but this won't work in the case where the src attribute is missing entirely ([src] is redundant in that case).

Comment: if src contains "images/Category/large/469.jpg" this will still hide the image which is wrong. please correct and i will accept your answer

Comment: @Super1 its working for me  http://jsfiddle.net/xx62q/6/.. if you have problem... please make a fiddle

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562442/jquery-filter-image-src-issues

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#EntityPic543").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

That will hide the element.