# jquery filter image src issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

if the image contains NO src then i want to hide the `div.PageHeaderDescription`

```
<div class="PageHeaderDescription">
  <h1>Bistro 300</h1>
    <img border="0" src="images/Category/large/469.jpg" id="EntityPic621">
    This is some text
</div>
```

To do this i used:

```
if ($("div.PageHeaderDescription img").filter("[src='']")) {
    $("div.PageHeaderDescription").hide();
}
```

however if you put a src path into the image the jquery still hides `div.PageHeaderDescription` which is wrong. It needs to be visable if there is an image src.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfasd/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter()` returns a jQuery object, which is always truthy, whether or not elements were matched.

What you should be doing instead is checking the `length`property of the object returned;

```
if ($("div.PageHeaderDescription img").filter("[src='']").length) {
    $("div.PageHeaderDescription").hide();
}
```

Although you could shorten this to;

```
if ($("div.PageHeaderDescription img[src='']").length) {
    $("div.PageHeaderDescription").hide();
}
```

But if you have multiple `div.PageHeaderDescription` on the page, you should be doing;

```
$("div.PageHeaderDescription").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);

    if (self.find('img[src=""]').length) {
        self.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div.PageHeaderDescription img[src='']").parent().hide();
```

Find `img` with empty `src` and hide its parent `div.PageHeaderDescription`;

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xx62q/21/)**

OR

```
$("div.PageHeaderDescription").has("img[src='']").hide();
```

Hide this `div.PageHeaderDescription` which has `img` with empty `src`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xx62q/24/)**

Comment: +1 Very elegant. May I suggest `$('img[src=''],img:not([src])','div.PageHeaderDescription').parent().hide();`

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that when page loads, you can use this code:

```
$("div.PageHeaderDescription img")     // search for all img's inside a div...
   .filter("[src='']")                 // get only ones with no src
   .parents("div.PageHeaderDescription")   // get their parent elements
   .hide(); // hide then
```

Or you can run the same script every time you want to check if any img with no src is in page and must be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it more complicated than it needs to be with a `.filter()`.

```
var phd = $("div.PageHeaderDescription");    
if ($('img:not([src])',phd).length || $('img[src=""]',phd).length) {
    phd.hide();
}
```

​

I check to see if the `img` doesn't have the `src` attribute or if it does have the attribute I check if it is blank.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/G6bPu/

Answer (score 0):

As already said, a jQuery object always evaluates to `true`. But you don't need an `if` statement at all, simply reduce the set of elements to those that have an "empty" image. That's what `.filter()` is there for:

```
$("div.PageHeaderDescription").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("img[src='']").length > 0;
}).hide();
```