# jquery + find the number of img elements with a populated src

Tags: jquery, html

** Update - trying to find the number of elements with an empty src ******

I need to find the number of img elements with a populated src - eg: not src=""

Trying this:

```
  if(!$('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer').find('img[src=""]').length > 0) {
    alert(numPhotos);
  }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="previewWrapper" id="thumbPreview3">
  <div class="previewContainer">
   <img src="" class="photoPreview" data-width="" data-height=""><span>3</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

thx

Comment: your question is a bit confusing...  do you want to find the img with empty or those that match parts of the src?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562442/jquery-filter-image-src-issues

Comment: The `!$(...).length > 0` actually negates the jQuery object, and then compares with `0`. But fixing it wouldn't set `numPhotos`.

Comment: -1 With the latest update your question is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var theNumber = $('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img[src=""]').length;
```

EDIT: jQuery has a neat != attribute selector
EDIT2: The OP now wants the number of images with empty src

Comment: I think this could be simplified by using `[src!=""]`.

Comment: right ... I always forget about the differences between CSS and jQuery selectors

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you want EMPTY SRC...
try this

```
$('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer img[src=""]').length;
```

You might want to read out the CSS Selector of jquery too

```
 http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
```

They have a lot more patterns you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate this so:

```
var srcNone = $('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer').find('img[src=""]').length;
var allImg = $('div.previewWrapper div.previewContainer').find('img').length;
var numPhotosWithSrc = allImg - srcNone;

alert(NumPhotosWithSrc);
```

Give it a try ;-)